# SharePoint 2010 approval workflow needs edit permission on site level

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, word, approval-process

We have a SharePoint 2013 environment with a document library. On this library we have added the 2010 approval workflow. It's configured to be started on publish of an item, or it can be manually started (needed for publish from Word). Everyone has read permissions on the site level. On the document library we have unique permissions. We have CRUD permissions for all users that need it.

When a user edit's his document, closes Word, and chooses to publish a primary item, the worklow isn't started. The user doesn't get the workflow start screen. Only when I give a user edit permissions on the site level the workflow starts when an item is published. Then we do get the workflow page when we publish from Word.

We don't need edit permissions on site level when we publish the document from the list view. Also when we manually try to start the workflow from the list view there is no issue.

So we only have an issue when the user tries to publish a primary version from Word. In this case site level edit permissions are needed to get the workflow start page. We don't want to give users edit permissions on the site level.

We are using the O365 suite (V1902)

Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: It might be because the user only have read permission on the associated workflow tasks list. If they are to be able to start a workflow, they need to be able to contribute to this list to create the corresponding task.

Comment: Users have full control on task and history list. But still same issue